# What does "permissive" statement mean in SELinux policy type enforcement (.te) file?

Tags: selinux

I'm defining a new type `mynewtype_t`. There is a line which was automatically generated with the `permissive` keyword.

```
$ sepolicy generate --init /bin/sh
Failed to retrieve rpm info for selinux-policy
Created the following files:
/tmp/policy/bash.te # Type Enforcement file
/tmp/policy/bash.if # Interface file
/tmp/policy/bash.fc # File Contexts file
/tmp/policy/bash_selinux.spec # Spec file
/tmp/policy/bash.sh # Setup Script
```

The contents of bash.te:

```
policy_module(bash, 1.0.0)

########################################
#
# Declarations
#

type bash_t;
type bash_exec_t;
init_daemon_domain(bash_t, bash_exec_t)

permissive bash_t;

########################################
#
# bash local policy
#
allow bash_t self:capability { chown setgid setuid };
allow bash_t self:process { fork setpgid setrlimit signal_perms };
allow bash_t self:fifo_file rw_fifo_file_perms;
allow bash_t self:unix_stream_socket create_stream_socket_perms;

domain_use_interactive_fds(bash_t)

files_read_etc_files(bash_t)

auth_use_nsswitch(bash_t)

miscfiles_read_localization(bash_t)

sysnet_dns_name_resolve(bash_t)
```

In the line:

```
permissive bash_t;
```

What does the `permissive` keyword represent?

Answer (score 1):

[`permissive` statement](https://selinuxproject.org/page/TypeStatements#permissive) allows type `bash_t` to run in permissive mode (instead of running whole system in permissive mode). Permissive mode is set with [`semanage`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/semanage-permissive.8.html).